# How to merge multiple entries in a data frame into a single entry, Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add all the balances of a customers accounts but I am having difficulties doing such. There are two columns, the `'Customer'` and the `'Balance'` column. The data frame looks like this:

```
Customer             Balance
John Doe account1      400
John Doe account2      600
John Doe account3      200
Jane Doe account1      500
Jane Doe account2      100
John Deer account1     800
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this: summing all the accounts' balances into just one account into another data frame or into the same data frame. Whichever is faster or easier.

```
Customer                  Balance
John Doe AccountX          1200
Jane Doe AccountX          600
John Deer AccountX         800
```

Can I please ask for some help regarding this matter? I can't seem to get around this problem. Sorry, still just a beginner programmer trying to learn. Thank you for your time, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: now you see what I mean right ?

Comment: Yeah, fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [181]: df.groupby(df.Customer.str[:-1].add('X'), sort=False).sum().reset_index()
Out[181]:
             Customer  Balance
0   John Doe accountX     1200
1   Jane Doe accountX      600
2  John Deer accountX      800
```